# Visualworks Cincom Smalltalk SUnit Test case for error condition

Tags: exception, error-handling, smalltalk, visualworks, gnu-smalltalk

I have this piece of code.

```
|temp|
temp := 5
(temp < 3) ifFalse:[
    self error: 'Invalid input'.
].
```

What will a SUnit test case look like, if I have to test that the above error is raised when I run this code?

Currently when I run the above code, it says "Unhandled exception: Invalid input"
How can I handle this exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
   testError
   |temp|
   temp := 5.
      self
         should: [(temp < 3) ifFalse:[
            self error: 'Invalid input']]
         raise: Error
```